# Vector space C over R's basis is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, I have to show that the dimension of the vector space C with scalars from R is 2.

$$
\text{Let } B = \{1, i\}, z \in \mathbb{C}\\
\text{Then } z=a+bi \text{ for some } a,b \in R\\
\text{Hence } z \text{ is a linear combination of the elements of } B \text{, so }span B = \mathbb{C}.
$$

To show they are linearly independent, I have to show that $a+bi = 0 \Rightarrow a=0 \land b=0$. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

When I finished writing it, I thought of a way, but I thought I'd post the question anyway. Here's what I did.

$$ a+bi = 0 \Rightarrow (a + bi)(a - b i)=0 \Rightarrow a^2 + b^2 =0$$

Since $a,b \in \mathbb R$, $a^2, b^2 \geq 0$. So $a^2 = 0$ and $b^2 = 0$. Hence $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: How did you define the complex numbers in the first place? Maybe this exercise is easier than you think..

Comment: As an ordered pair. And $(a, b) = (0, 0) \Rightarrow a=0 \land b=0$

Comment: So should I just work with ordered pairs all the way through, instead of using $a + bi$

Comment: If you define them as ordered couples, operations on them must be done accordingly. If you define them this way however, $(a, b) = (0, 0) \Rightarrow a=0 \land b=0$ seems to be linear independence served on a silver platter!

Comment: You seem to be confusing what you have as definitions and what you have to prove. I am sure once you clear this up it will look trivial to you.

Answer (score -1):

Given that $a+ib=0$, we can write the right hand side 
                     $$0=0+i0$$
So we get
$$       a+ib=0+i0$$
On comparing real and imaginary part we get
$      a=0$
and $b=0$.
Which show that $B$ is L.I. because $a,b \in \Bbb R$ are both zero.